# implementing an equivalent of the C#'s null test in F#

Tags: f#

I'm using quite a lot this piece of code:

```
let inline (||>) (a: 'a option) (b: 'a -> unit) = if a.IsSome then b a.Value
```

so I can do things like

```
myData ||> DoSomethingWithIt
```

without having to test if *myData* is Some or None since there are many functions that don't generally need to test for an option. This avoid to put the test in the function itself.

I would like to extend this to methods of a type where I could do like C#'s:

```
myData?.DoSomethingWithIt
```

essentially replacing:

```
if myData.IsSome then myData.Value.DoSomethingWithIt
```

with some syntactic sugar.

but I have no idea how I could do the operator so that it allows to get access to the type's method in the expression. Is that possible in F#?

I'm also open to learn about why it could be a bad idea if it is :)

Comment: Overriding `||>` is bad idea because it's predefined operator used for tuple deconstruction `(1, 2) ||> printfn "%d %d"` and some code might break if somebody try to open your module

Comment: @JL0PD, I had no idea about that! thank for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your return type of `DoSomethingWithIt` the F# library offers a few standard functions for working with Options that can be turned into operators.

```
let x = Some 1

let aPrinter a = printfn "%i" a
let add1 a = a + 1

let (|?>) opt f = Option.iter f opt
let (|??>) opt f = Option.map f opt

x |?> aPrinter
let y = x |??> add1
```

You can also consider redefining your `DoSomethingWithIt` to work with an option by partial application.

```
let DoSomethingWithIt' = Option.iter DoSomethingWithIt 
let something' = Option.iter (fun (b:B) -> b.DoSomethingWithIt()) //For instance methods
```

That may end up being a lot of work depending how many functions you are dealing with.
Ultimately you shouldn't try to hide the fact you are working with Options. By making something an Option you are telling the compiler that you aren't sure whether it exists or not. It is trying to help you by forcing you to deal with the None case. If there are lots of cases in your code where you know your Option is Some then there's probably a larger architectural issue in your code and you should try to lift all your Option<'T> to just T prior to doing work with them. e.g.:

```
let lift xs = 
    [
        for x in xs do 
            match x with
            | Some x -> yield x
            | None -> ()
    ]
```

Comment: to give a bit of context, I'm processing a very large amount of messages sent by a server and these messages may / may not include some values depending on what data was updated. So while I am aware that the types are option, pretty much every single interaction is happening only if the type is Some. But since there are easily over 50 fields with that condition, I'm trying to hide the check. But I wasn't aware of Option.iter which does exactly what I need!

Comment: In that kind of scenario what I'd suggest for the most robust solution would be to write a `messageClassifier` function to turn each message into one of several types (wrapped in a DU) based on which fields actually have values. That lets you eliminate all Options up front and makes explicit each kind of message you're dealing with.

Comment: but the number of combinations would explode. This is an example of a message I'm getting (https://pastebin.com/iCa5eEdu), which originates in C#. There  are 29 fields, at any given time, roughly half may not be present in the json message and maybe 10 or so are mandatory. I can't list all combinations; or am I missing something?

Comment: In principle there may be billions of combinations but in practice there's likely to only be a handful of combinations that the server actually sends. A nested structure (DU of another DU) may also be appropriate.

Comment: The variety is quite high because the data is following financial trades and fields may be present, or not, based on calculations that have changed since the last time, so the server is kind of expecting the client to make a delta based on the missing fields. And, of course, I want to only process the updated ones so I can’t just make a delta and run run the processing. There is some, but very limited, grouping of fields I can do but overall they have mostly to be treated one by one

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Option.iter. It has the same signature as your operator.

Answer (score 1):

There is no analogical syntax for such constructions but F# have alternatives.
The easiest way is to use [FSharpx.Extras](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras) library and `FSharpx.Option.maybe` [computation expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions) which will allow you to  use `Option` related operations.

```ml
open FSharpx.Option

let a = Some 1
let b = maybe {
    let! v = a
    return v + 3
} // b is (Some 4)

let c : int option = None
let d = maybe {
    let! v = c
    return v + 3 // this line won't be reached
} // d is None
```

Comment: that will not work because the idea is to make it as terse as possible, if I am to use a computation expression, might as well do the test on the value, then run the code if the test passes

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the `?.` operator in c# is a syntactic sugar that hides the if statement checking for null before invoking a member of the type. Even if you could make it work the way you plan, I feel that it would go against the FP principles and could cause more problems down the line.

The Option module contains probably most of what you need already. The iter function allows to call a function on the value of the Option *if* that value is present (*Some*).

If you have situation that your input parametes can be nulls, but not options, you can use the Option.ofObj function that will convert the parameter to an Option with *Some* if the parameter is not null, else *None*.

So assuming that your function `DoSomethingWithit` accepts a string and returns unit:

```
   let DoSomethingWithIt = //(string -> unit)
       printf "%s; "
```

You can use this more verbose syntax to (for example) iterate over nullable values in your list:

```
   let lst = [ "data"; "data 2"; null; "data3" ]
   lst
   |> List.iter (fun v -> v |> Option.ofObj |> Option.iter DoSomethingWithIt)
```

Alternatively you can compose the `Optioni.ofObj` and `Option.iter DoSomethingWithIt` functions and do something like

```
   let SafeDoSomethingWithIt = //(string -> unit)
      Option.ofObj >> Option.iter DoSomethingWithIt
```

This gives you safe invocation:

```
   let lst2 = [ "data"; "data 2"; null; "data3" ]
   lst2
   |> List.iter SafeDoSomethingWithIt
```

You can generalize the combination of the functions returning *unit* (but not only)

```
   let makeSafe fn =
      Option.ofObj >> Option.iter fn
```

Then you can create a series of safe functions:

```
   let SafeDoSomethingWithIt = makeSafe DoSomethingWithIt 
   
   let safePrint = makeSafe (printf "%s; ")

   //...etc
```

Then this still works:

```
   lst2
   |> List.iter SafeDoSomethingWithIt
   
   lst2
   |> List.iter safePrint
```

You can also write a wrapper for functions returning values using *Option.bind* function.

```
   let makeSafeReturn fn = //(string -> string option)
       Option.ofObj >> Option.bind fn
```